# String.xml does not get updated in Android

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

When I add this code to activity_main.xml , I get an error because the value in `string.xml` doesn't exist..

What should I do, besides manually changing the value in `string.xml`?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unknown"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: are you sure you are opening same project's string.xml file ?

Comment: please state what kind of error you're getting and how do you change unknown to hello world? I think this is the place you got something mixed up.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "I change my value android:text in main.xml"

Comment: can u post ur strings.xml code.

Comment: have u defined a resource unknown in res/values/strings.xml??. can u pls post the code of strings.xml. It has to be strings.xml. You say string.xml. So i doubt whether you have defined resource in the correct strings.xml

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing a string  **Hello wolrd** in **strings.xml** which is not present in the strings.xml file.

You cannot change the values in strings.xml programatically.

You can do the following to change the text in textview programatically.

```
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
tv.setText("hello");

or
tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.my_string));// refer to the string in strings.xml programatically.
```

You can set text in xml

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textSize="20dip" >
```

In Strings.xml

```
    <string name="my_String">Hello World</string>
```

In xml file you can reference the above string

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/my_string"
    android:textSize="20dip" >
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html. Have a look at the link.

A example from the link above.

XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>// hello is defined here in strings.xml
  </resources>
```

This layout XML applies a string to a View:

```
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello" />// resource hello is refered here.
```

Comment: Okay, Maybe I did not explain it correctly. My apologizes. i changed my main.xml to the code I changed. Then i got a red line under android:text :"@string/unknown" and says value not found in string.xml. What to do> to get rid of red line and error

Comment: that is because you have to define the resource unknown in strings.xml. you can reference the same in your main.xml text view or refer it programatically to set text in textview. check if you have defined a string unknown in strings.xml

Answer (score 2):

Sounds simple but I was having the same issue. I solved it by just restarting Android Studio.